# Comparisons using Quicksort with the median as the pivot

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, asymptotics, recurrence-relation, big-o-notation

### Background

Using a simplified Quicksort algorithm where the first element of the array is assigned as the pivot we get the following pseudocode for the algorithm:

> **Quicksort($a$):**
>
> - (1) If length($a$) $> 1$, then
>
> > - 1.1) pivot $← a [1]$.
> > - 1.2) less $← a[a <$ pivot].
> > - 1.3) equals $← a[a ==$ pivot].
> > - 1.4) greater $← a[a >$ pivot].
> > - 1.5) $a ←$ concat(Quicksort(less), equals, Quicksort(greater)).
>
> - (2) Output $a$.

It is clear to see that the total number of comparisons will follow the recurrence equation:

$$C(n) = C(n-1) + (n-1) \space \space \text{ where } \space C(2) = 1$$

From here we see that $C(n) = \Theta (n^2)$

Here is the context under which  this came up:

> [image]

### Question

The above is clear to me, however, I have now read that if we use the median as a pivot (which can be identified in $\Theta (n)$ time), then we get the following recurrence inequality:

$$ C(n) \leq 2C ( \lceil n/2 \rceil -1) + Mn $$

And this gives the result that $C(n) = \Theta (n \log n)$.

---

How have these two results been derived (the recurrence inequality and time complexity for the updated algorithm)? The only difference is that we are computing the median each time. This is achieved in $\Theta (n)$ time each time that it is calculated but it still isn't entirely clear where this inequality comes from or why the new time complexity is $\Theta(n \log n)$ for the entire algorithm.

---

Here is the exact context under which it came up:

> [image]

Comment: (Output $a$ in each recursive call?)

Comment: For $C(n) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, we have $0.5 n^2 \leq C(n) \leq n^2$ for some $n \ge n_0$  @greybeard

Comment: Does this not suggest that $C(n) \in O(n^2)$ **and** $C(n) \in \Omega (n^2)$? And if it is both, then that means $C(n) \in \Theta (n^2)$ as suggested in the post @greybeard

Comment: Yes. They may be smaller (many items equal to pivot). Another reason not to be happy with theta…

Comment: If we are only looking for a formula for the worst case run time, then I think we should assume that there are no items equal to the pivot @greybeard

Comment: (Exchanging comments isn't StackExchange style. One problem with your question is not stating where specifically you are stuck.)

Comment: The question itself asks about the derivation of this inequality: $ C(n) \leq 2C ( \lceil n/2 \rceil -1) + Mn $. I don't know where that comes from and that is the answer I am looking for @greybeard

Comment: It then says that this implies that $C(n) = O(n \log n)$, and so I was wondering what the relationship between that and the previous inequality is too @greybeard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The genuine Quicksort is an in-place algorithm, and your version with concatenations uses extra memory and is much less efficient for this reason [$\Theta(n^2)$ instead of $O(n^2)$ with best case $O(n\log n)$]. Also, it is a waste of time to apply the trichotomy <, =, >, which costs two comparisons where you can do with a single.

This said, the behavior of Quicksort relies on the "balancing" of the pivot: it every pivot generates a partition with a single element on a side and the rest on the other side, the total complexity is indeed proportional to $n+(n-1)+(n-2)+\cdots $, which is $\Theta(n^2)$.

But if every pivot splits the array in two equal halves, the total complexity is like $n+\dfrac n2+\dfrac n2+\dfrac n4+\dfrac n4+\dfrac n4+\dfrac n4+\cdots$, which equals $n\log_2n$.

---

Note that Quicksort is *never* implemented with the median taken as the pivot, because the linear-time median algorithm is complicated and much slower than the partitioning process itself. If one needs an algorithm with *guaranteed* worst-case complexity $O(n\log n)$, Heapsort is a better choice.

Comment: @greybeard: the first paragraph does not assume a median pivot.  Just a plea against this version.

Comment: (I hope not: Θ(n²) effort for all slices/copies combined, not for a single one.)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. That clarifies the second part of my question. I’m still unsure about where the recurrence inequality comes from though

Comment: @FD_bfa: simply from "to sort $n$ elements, partition the array in two halves and sort them separately".

Comment: My understanding is that $Mn$ is the number of comparisons needed to find the median and $2C( \lceil n/2 \rceil )$ accounts for the number of comparisons after we have split the array in half. But this doesn’t seem to include the $n-1$ comparisons with the pivot in order to assign each element to one of the 2 arrays

Comment: @FD_bfa: $M$ can be anything.

Comment: So should we not say: $ C(n) \leq 2C ( \lceil n/2 \rceil -1) + Mn -1 $? (with the addition of a $(-1)$ at the end)

Comment: @FD_bfa: the $-1$ are useless, the expressions are anyway approximate. And you have an inequality.